# PHP Standard value is NULL and won't update

Tags: php, mysql, database

in my database i have some tables, i have one for the image path, and one for the image width, they have a standard value of NULL, and a null value (the checkbox and the dropdown box is both NULL)
When i enter a new path or width it does not change, but my other does, this is my code.

```
require_once("../Packages/Connection.php");

$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["articleText"]);
$method = $_POST['method'];
$articleId = $_POST['articleId'];
$imagePath = $_POST['imagePath'];
$imageWidth = $_POST['imageWidth'];

if($method == "update")
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE Articles SET text='$text' WHERE id='$articleId'") or die(mysql_error());
}
elseif($method == "delete")
{
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM Articles WHERE id=".$articleId."");
};

if($_POST["articleGroup"]=="News")
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Articles VALUES(NULL,'".$_POST["articleGroup"]."','".time()."','".$text."', NULL, NULL, NULL)") or die(mysql_error());
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Articles VALUES (NULL,'".$_POST["articleGroup"]."','NULL','".$text."','NULL','".$imagePath."','".$imageWidth."')") or die(mysql_error());  
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Input sanitization: you're doing it wrong. Read: http://bobby-tables.com/. This applies to *all* user input.

Comment: please run "show create table Articles;" in MySQL and provide the result

Answer (score 1):

There's no UPDATE for the other two fields.

```
UPDATE Articles SET text='$text' WHERE id='$articleId'
```

should include updating (add to the SET clause) the other fields.

As others have said, you should sanitize other fields as well (and probably move from the deprecated extension - update PHP if necessary) otherwise any sanitizing you are doing is pointless as an attacked can use the other fields

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by `move from the deprecated extension?`

Comment: @Landon http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php mysql_query is depricated. You should use mysqli or PDO instead

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the other two attributes to your update command.  It would be helpful to know your mysql table schema, but guessing the column names, I get:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Articles SET text='".$text."', width='".$imageWidth."', path='".$imageWidth."' WHERE id='".$articleId."'");
```

Also, as the commenters pointed out, you **really** need to sanitize your input values.  Any REQUEST variable needs to be checked/sanitized.  You can read more about this [here](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)